# Adding countdowntime to system time

Tags: android, countdown

A bit confusing this one but should make sense.
Thanks to all your help I have my app now showing a custom digital clock and a countdowntimer (02:30:00 countdown) running under it.

How do I add 02:30:00 to the current time so a new clock field shows the current time + the countdown?

Thanks

Dj

This is my digitalclock code where would i put the offset to ad 2 hours 30 mins to time...

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        timer = new Timer("DigitalClock");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                countdown.setText(getCurrentTimeString());
            }
        };
    int msec = 999 - calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(updateTask);
        }
    }, msec, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
    private String getCurrentTimeString() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
//      int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand your question :p, I think the only way to do that is to reimplement a DigitalClock. Take [its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/DigitalClock.java) and play with it by adding an offset to the hours and minutes.

UPDATE:

What I would do is take that code and change this part:

```
    mTicker = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mTickerStopped) return;
                mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar));
                invalidate();
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
            }
        };
    mTicker.run();
```

Convert 2:30:00 to milliseconds and add it to now :

```
long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + offset;
```

Comment: Hi, I have used Countdowntimer to make the app countdown from 2 hours and 30 mins and then repeats automatically but what I also would like to show is a system clock with the added 2 hours and 30 mins...so basically a time in the future that updates each time the countdwontime ends.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question in the first place. Have a look at my update.

Comment: Ah I see where you are going with that, the clock code I am using was modified to fit my needs but i thin the code had reference to 00:00:00 which then adds the system time to the it...so maybe if I change it to 02:30:00 it might do if not I'll pop my code into this thread?

Comment: Dude you are on my christmas card list, thanks will give it a bash :)

Comment: you can approve the answer by clicking on the green check on the left. ;)

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on how to achieve the offset within my existing code?